# LayeredGraphPlot: how to specify edge endpoints?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks

What directive within the `LayeredGraphPlot` command specifies where the edges attach to vertices?  For example, instead of the left output below, I'd like to have the right one.

[image] [image]

```
gph = {{
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<13\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<14\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<24\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<26\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<36\>"\)]\)} -> {\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<14\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<16\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<24\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<26\>"\)]\)}, {\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<13\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<16\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<24\>"\)]\), 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<26\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<34\>"\)]\)} -> {\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<14\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<16\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<24\>"\)]\), 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<26\>"\)]\)}, {\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<14\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<15\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<24\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<26\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<56\>"\)]\)} -> {
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<14\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<16\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<24\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<26\>"\)]\)}, {\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<14\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<16\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<23\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<24\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<36\>"\)]\)} -> {\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<14\>"\)]\), 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<16\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<24\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<26\>"\)]\)}, {\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<14\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<16\>"\)]\),   \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<23\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<26\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<34\>"\)]\)} -> {\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<14\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<16\>"\)]\),     \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<24\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<26\>"\)]\)}, {\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<14\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<16\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<24\>"\)]\),     \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<25\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<56\>"\)]\)} -> {\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<14\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<16\>"\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<24\>"\)]\),    \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("\<e\>"\), \("\<26\>"\)]\)}};
LayeredGraphPlot[gph, Right, VertexLabeling->True, DirectedEdges->False, SelfLoopStyle->False, PlotRangePadding->0]
```

**Edit:** The following Mathematica code (answer below)

```
ClearAll[n, k, g, \[Mu], \[Mu]\[Mu], \[CapitalGamma]0, 
\[CapitalGamma]1]; n = 4; 
multiComplement = Join@@(ConstantArray[First@#,Max[Last@#,0]]& /@ (Tally[#1]/.(Tally[#2]/.{e_,c_Integer} :> {e,k_Integer}->{e,k-c})))&;
g = Flatten[Table[{a, b}, {a, 1, n}, {b, a, n}], 1]; dim = Length@g;
\[Mu][{a_, a_}, {b_, b_}] := 0; \[Mu][{a_, a_}, {b_, c_}] := If[a == b || a == c, {b, c}, 0]; \[Mu][{a_, b_}, {c_, c_}] := If[a == c || b == c, {a, b}, 0]; 
\[Mu][{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}] := Which[b == c, {a, d}, a == d, {c, b}, True, 0]; lft={1,1}; rgt={4,4};
\[CapitalGamma]0 = Select[Subsets[g,{1}], Sort[multiComplement[First/@#, Last/@#]] == lft && Sort[multiComplement[Last/@ #,First/@#]] == rgt &]; \[CapitalGamma]1={}; 
For[k=2, k<=dim, k++, TT=Select[Subsets[g,{k}], Sort[multiComplement[First/@#, Last/@#]]==lft && Sort[multiComplement[Last/@#,First/@#]]==rgt&]; \[CapitalGamma]0=Join[\[CapitalGamma]0, TT]; 
 For[l = 1, l <= Length@TT, l++, tt = TT[[l]]; 
  For[i = 1, i <= k, i++,
   For[j = i + 1, j <= k, j++, \[Mu]\[Mu]=\[Mu][tt[[i]],tt[[j]]]; 
    If[\[Mu]\[Mu] == 0, Continue[]];
    t = Join[tt[[1;;i-1]], tt[[i+1;;j-1]], tt[[j+1;;k]]]; 
    If[MemberQ[t, \[Mu]\[Mu]], Continue[]];  ii=1;  
    For[jj = 1;, ii <= Length@t, jj++, If[g[[jj]] == t[[ii]], ii++]; 
     If[g[[jj]]==\[Mu]\[Mu], Break[]]];
    t = Join[t[[1;;ii-1]], {\[Mu]\[Mu]}, t[[ii;;-1]]]; 
    \[CapitalGamma]1 = Append[\[CapitalGamma]1, tt->t];]]]]
gph = Join[\[CapitalGamma]1, #->#&/@ \[CapitalGamma]0] /. {a_Integer, b_Integer} :> Subscript["e", ToString[a] <> ToString[b]];
LayeredGraphPlot[gph, Right, VertexLabeling->True, DirectedEdges->False, SelfLoopStyle->False, MultiedgeStyle->None, PlotRangePadding->0] /.
 Text[Framed[x_,z___],y_] :> With[{ap=Switch[x,gph[[1,2]],{Right,Center},_,{Left,Center}]}, Text[Framed[x,z],y,ap]]
```

produces 
[image]
which is not the desired effect.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** The offset trick in the original answer works only for two-layer graphs. For more than two layers, we need to take into account the sizes of the vertex labels to translate the lines by appropriate amounts. This is achieved in several steps with the end result:

[image]

**Step 0:** Using the update version of `gph` and deleting duplicates:

```
lgp = LayeredGraphPlot[DeleteDuplicates @ gph, Right, ImageSize -> 1200, 
   VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> False, 
   SelfLoopStyle -> False, MultiedgeStyle -> None, ImageSize -> 1000, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/2];
```

**Step 1:** Extract labels and vertices from `lgp`:

```
labels = Cases[lgp, Text[f_, a__] :> f, {0, Infinity}];
vertices = labels[[All, 1]];
```

**Step 2:** Extract plot range and image dimensions:

```
rs = Rasterize[lgp, "RasterSize"];
prF1 = Charting`CommonDump`getplotrange[#, AxesOrigin /. Options[#, AxesOrigin]] &;
ps = -Subtract @@@ prF1[lgp];
```

**Step 3:** Rescale the coordinates:

```
rescaledlgp = lgp /. GraphicsComplex[c : {__}, p__] :> 
    GraphicsComplex[Transpose[{Round @ Rescale[#, {0, ps[[1]]}, {0, rs[[1]]}], 
         Round @ Rescale[#2, {0, ps[[2]]}, {0, rs[[2]]}]} & @@ Transpose[c]], p];

vcoords = rescaledlgp[[1, 1, 1]];
```

**Step 4:** Compute the amounts by which to translate the edges based on label sizes:

```
hlength = -Subtract @@ (prF1[rescaledlgp][[1]]);
ClearAll[vCoordRule, hOffset]
vCoordRule = Thread[vertices -> vcoords];
Table[hOffset[ll[[1]] /. vCoordRule] = Rescale[Rasterize[Style[ll, "Graphics"], 
 "RasterSize"][[1]]/2, {0, rs[[1]]}, {0, hlength}], {ll, labels}];
```

**Step 5:** Post-process to modify the lines:

```
Show[rescaledlgp /. {Text[t_, b_] :> Text[t, Scaled@vcoords[[b]]], 
 Line[p : {{_, _} ..}] :> 
   (Line[{Scaled[(# - {hOffset[#], 0}) &@ vcoords[[#[[1]]]]], 
         Scaled[(# + {hOffset[#], 0}) &@ vcoords[[#[[2]]]]]}] & /@ (# & /@ p))} , 
  AspectRatio -> 1,  ImageSize -> 1500] // Magnify[#, 1/2] &
```

gives the picture above.

**Note:** You might need to resize to avoid overlaps.

**Original answer:**

```
lgp1 = LayeredGraphPlot[gph, Right, VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> False, 
   SelfLoopStyle -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 400];
```

Post-process `lgp1` to add the appropriate alignment point (`{Right, Center}` for the root vertex and `{Left, Center}` for the leaves) to the `Text` primitives representing the vertex labels:

```
lgp2 = lgp1 /. Text[Framed[x_, z___], y_] :>
   With[{ap = Switch[x, gph[[1, 2]], {Right, Center}, _, {Left, Center}]}, 
        Text[Framed[x, z], y, ap]]

Row[{lgp1, lgp2}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Comment: ... not sure if the same trick can be made to work for more than two layers.

Comment: Doesn't work as it should; see my edit above.

Comment: @Leon, right, it doesn't; as is it works for only two-layer graphs as in your original example. Hence my comment just above yours -- i should have had "I seriously doubt..." instead of "not sure...":) Good question btw. I think constructing a `EdgeRenderingFunction` that takes into account the sizes/shapes of vertex labels might be possible but i can't think of an easy way to do that.